# When and how are dead followers gained from the Leadership feat replaced?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, followers-and-hirelings

The feat [Leadership](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/leadership---final) has changed considerably since 3.X days and has brought up a few debates at my table.

The specific debate is not over cohorts, but over followers. Let's say my level 7 Pathfinder Cleric has a leadership score of 12, this means he gains a cohort of level 5 and 8 level 1 followers with a PC class. If my Cleric were to arm his followers with weapons, take them into battle, and they all died, would he be able to gain more followers (after figuring in the -1 to his score for having followers killed under him)?

So, my question is this: **If your followers die, are you able to gain more, or do you have to wait until either you level or your leadership score increases?**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

My interpretation of the rules would be that the player can recruit more followers at the next opportunity, though they wouldn't *magically appear*.  The rule only references the table for "acquire more followers" presumably in contrast with the number you previously had.

As a DM I would say:

- Your leadership score is reduced by one for loss of previous followers (unless the loss was suitably epic).
- You can recruit more followers as soon as you are able to spend a reasonable amount of time in a reasonably populous area.

Comment: That's pretty much what I was thinking. You can recruit new cohorts, so no reason you couldn't recruit more followers. It is nice to note that you only ever get a -1 if followers die (unlike the cumulative cohort negative upon death..)